# valid signing identity not found for distribution

Tags: xcode, distribution, provisioning

I just wanted to submit my first iphone app to the app store. Therefore I created a provisioning profile for distribution. However, after installing it in XCode, it tells me "valid signing identity not found". How do I repair this?

This is my current situation described in pictures:

[image]

What do I have to do?